# Reaction NodeJS development workflow

Tags: node.js, meteor, hot-reload, reaction-commerce

I am starting to use reaction Reaction, the NodeJS ecommerce framework, and I am trying to understand how is the development workflow.

The thing is that I use the reaction-cli to create the app, then just to understand how does it works, I edited the file located at `imports/plugins/core/layout/client/notFound/notFound.html` but I can't see the edited content on the site.

Does it include any "hot reloading" feature ? using `reaction debug` does not work also.

Btw: I know that editing core components is not the best way, but I was trying to understand and check the hot reloading feature because does not has any sense to recompile the project everytime that I modify a file, moving forwards I will use a custom plugin or theme.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Reaction Commerce doesn't feature Hot Module Reloading out of the box. Any change to your project's code will trigger a build.

Although the current Reaction developer experience can sometimes be frustrating (especially on larger projects), a detached, Next.js and GraphQL based storefront [is being built](https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction-next-starterkit). With the client side being detached from the back-end, changes to the front-end code are picked up instantly.

Comment: Yes but why the build trigger does not work when modifying a core component ?

Comment: Have you tried stopping Reaction and restarting it altogether? Were the changes picked up?